# Compare two cells as formatted

Tags: excel, vba

I have been asked to remove a one-line *UDF()* from a workbook to facilitate moving the workbook to a macro free environment.  The *UDF()* compares two cells "as formatted":

```
Public Function fEXACT(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Boolean
    fEXACT = (r1.Text = r2.Text)
End Function
```

[image]

I don't care about the font, alignment, etc.  If it matters, the target environment will be Excel 365.  Neither:

```
=D3=E3
=EXACT(D3,E3)
```

work.  Is there a formula replacement for the *UDF()* ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=AND(EXACT(D3,E3),CELL("format",D3)=CELL("format",E3))
```

[image]